# echo php code - how to do this

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo some php code in php:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
echo "<li><a href='profile.php'><?php echo $profile ?></a></li>";
}else{
echo "<li><a href='login.php'>login</a></li>";
}
```

`$profile` is in 3 languages thats why it is a variable.

this code isnot working for me. it is echoing nothing. how can i echo php code?

Comment: You can concatenate: `echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>" . $profile . "</a></li>";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) `.`, like this:

```
echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>" . $profile . "</a></li>";
```

Comment: I always wondered, what version was it that added support for `,` in echo's?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy It's probably for a while, `echo` is a language construct not an actual function, so I'm guessing since `echo`'s first implementation. There are no changes to it in its changelog in the docs.

Comment: Thanks. I'm no expert, but I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>$profile</a></li>";
}else{
echo "<li><a href='login.php'>login</a></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a choice. You can either use double quotes (`"`) or single quotes (`'`). The difference is that double quotes don't require concatenation:

---

Double quotes:

```
echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>$profile</a></li>";
```

Single quotes:

```
echo '<li><a href="profile.php">' . $profile . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: `\n`, `\t`, etc is printet rater then linebrak, tab when using `'`

Comment: @PeterVR - Double quotes are certainly not always better for performance, but this choice is a micro-optimization, as no application could ever bottleneck here.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the interpreter.

```
echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>", $profile ,"</a></li>";
```

that's all.

Comment: Actually, it's passing the string, the variable and the string as parameters. It's suppose to faster than string concatenation, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Note that if you're using double quotes (`"`), concatenation is optional :)

Comment: Although it's working, I find this notation very disturbing and misleading. Isn't it already disturbing enough to use a point to concatenate ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using double `"`s the string will be processed without concatenation.

```
echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>$profile</a></li>";
```

You can concatenate if you're dealing with prices in U.S. Currency where you would need the `$` character to be literal. But there really is no need outside of code readability.

```
 echo 'Price: $'.$profile;
```

Code like this affords you the ability to do checks on contents, verifying of information and still keep the dynamic functionality of PHP. Whereas if you mix HTML and PHP you will run into issues where you have to rewrite large sections to make something dynamic in the future.

Ideally you would make everything in PHP:

```
<?php
$mystring = "<ul>";

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $mystring .= "<li><a href='profile.php'>$profile</a></li>";
}else{
    $mystring .= "<li><a href='login.php'>login</a></li>";
}

$mystring .= "</ul>";
$page .= $mystring;

if ($dynamic_site == 1){
 print $page;
} else {
 //For static caching (much faster)
 fwrite ...
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a redundant answer because everyone else already said it, but you really should avoid printing html in php. Instead, break out of php to write html:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])): ?>
    <li><a href='profile.php'><?php echo $profile ?></a></li>
<?php else: ?>
    <li><a href='login.php'>login</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Not that it doesn't work the other way, it's just cleaner this way... according to general opinion I suppose.

Comment: I think the main thing is that you shouldn't mix server-side and client-side.

Comment: It's not pretty, but I tend to do this, too.

Comment: True. And there may be times when it makes sense to spit out a little html in php but im my experience I would say those times are as close to zero as it can get in a client based world.

Comment: in what context do you mean by groups? As for faster - cache the output. In any case where the processing speed for something like this really matters, the developers should be implementing a cache reader instead of straight interpretation. Otherwise, spare the eyes of anyone maintaining the code. 99.9% of the sites out there are so small this wouldn't matter one bit.

Comment: I usually take it a step farther and have a PHP method that encapsulates the session check and returns the string so in the markup, there's just one PHP function call and no if condition.

Comment: @absolute - I work in a firm with dozens of developers. This is the office standard. Not just from us. I argued it at first as well, but in the end I do find it easier to read. Most likely cause sometimes other people's code can be foreign in appearance and at least these statements make it easier to identify than brackets strewn about

Comment: Well I guess that would be a matter of organization or preference or something cause we never experience the problems you're speaking of. I still don't see how it would affect portability of anything this way.

Comment: You know what, thinking about this from a different perspective any performance gains on the server can easily be wiped out by slow bandwidth connections on the user side of things. If the server's not getting insanely amounts of high traffic it won't be an issue.

Comment: When inline `jquery`, `javascript`, `xml <cdata>`, `html 4` and `xhtml` are all intermixed with `PHP` it makes it harder to follow visually. If it's only `PHP` and one standard `HTML` this should be fine.

Comment: I feel your pain zero. By these comments you must have had to inherit more rancid code than even I have. Client world, you never know what you will get and most likely it will be bad. Only in my nightmares have I had to deal with mixtures like you speak of - or at least all inclusive. Still, I can optimize the code all I want. If a designer makes an illogical spritesheet it negates the load time as well. In most cases, the load times of the sites I work on aren't really an issue, or at least they don't raise questions.

Answer (score 2):

One more answer is needed:

```
<?php
    echo isset($_SESSION['id']) ? '<li><a href="profile.php">' . $profile . '</a></li>' : '<li><a href="login.php">login</a></li>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
echo '<li><a href="profile.php">' . $profile . '</a></li>';
}else{
echo '<li><a href="login.php">login</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake here is that you cannot have PHP tags within PHP tags.

If you use double quotes you can simply include the variable directly into the string.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>$profile</a></li>";
}else{
    echo "<li><a href='login.php'>login</a></li>";
}
```

Problem solved.